# I am getting Error 1396 trying to create a new user on a freshly installed mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I am getting the error:
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'testuser'@'localhost'
The command I am using is:
CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpass';

This is a brand new install of mariadb on debian 12 so the user testuser was never created.
I am not sure how to fix this error, everything I read suggests this happens when the user was improperly deleted, but as I said, the user was never created before.

Comment: are you performing this operation as root or some other user?

Comment: As root, and I double checked with select user(),CURRENT_USER();

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was used to using MySQL, where I could create a user with a dash: user-other, however it appears that MariaDB does not allow a dash in the username.
It works when I take out the dash.

Comment: hmm, your testuser from original post does not have a dash ;)